# Using karate built-in functions and api

Tags: karate

Ok, so I am going to explain what my scenario is and how I have implemented it using karate. But i am looking for a better way of doing things which make my tests more readable and also want to use karate's api rather than too much javascript.

**Scenario: I have a filter parameter for the api endpoint that i am testing and this filter param takes a json object of key-value pairs. So i have done the following**:

1. Have created a filter-template.js as below:

```
function() {
    var filter_params = {
        jobId:null,
        customerIds:[],
        filterValues1:[],
        filterValues2:[], 
    };
    return filter_params;
}
```

2. I read this template in my karate scenario and because this is a template, at runtime i set the values in this template and run the test. I will have different values for key-value pairs so each test will set its own filter condition. 
   This is done by writing custom js function that takes the template as argument and also the filter condition values (referring to arg function argument below), sets the passed conditions to specific key's and then returns json object. Code below:

```
Scenario: Set filter scenario
    * def filter_template = call read('filter-template.js')
    * def filter_vals_list = [1001,1002]
    * def filter_condition = { cnd1: 'foo', cnd2: '#(filter_vals_list)' }
    * def setFilter =
    """
      function(arg) {
        var i;
        var filter = arg.template;
        filter.jobId = arg.condition.cnd1;
        for(i=0;i<arg.condition.cnd2.length;i++)
        {
          filter.filterValues1.add(arg.condition.cnd2.get(i));
        }
        return filter;
      }
    """
    * def getFilter = call setFilter { template: '#(filter_template)', 
      condition: '#(filter_condition)' }
```

I then pass the getFilter as a param to my api request.

What I am hoping to understand is:

1. How can i get away from using JS loops above when setting filter?
2. Use karate's in-built functions like `karate.map()`, `karate.forEach()` to simplify the tests.
3. Any better approach if possible on tackling this scenario.

Help and guidance much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, I have simplified your scenario below:

```
* def filter_vals_list = [ 1001, 1002 ]
* def job_id = 'foo'
* def filter_template =
"""
{
  jobId: '#(job_id)',
  customerIds: [],
  filterValues1: '#(filter_vals_list)',
  filterValues2: [], 
}
"""
```

Let me know if I missed anything. Please refer embedded expressions: https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

Now, you can easily use a re-usable JSON for the template, by changing the last step to the below, and yes - embedded expressions work even in re-usable JSON files !

```
* def filter_template = read('filter-template.json')
```

You may get even better ideas once you try the [data-driven `Scenario Outline`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements). So hope that makes it clear how you are un-necessarily complicating things with JS ! You don't even need `karate.map()` etc.

Comment: thanks for simplifying this. Like the use of embedded expressions.